Combinatorial proof of a variation of Vandermonde's Identity
$$\sum_{r=0}^{a-b} \binom {a}{r+b} \binom {c}{d-r}=\binom{a+c}{b+d}$$
So far I have tried similar to original Vandermonde identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{a}{k} \binom {c}{r - k}= \binom{a+c}{r}$$
The combinatorial proof for this is intuitive: LFH: Let's say we have a group of a males and c females and we want to form a group of r members. So we take first k from the a males for the group, then we need in the group other r - k members that we choose from the c females. All the ways of taking that for values of k=0 to r are the ways of counting all the groups of r size of a+c people (RHS).
But I can't find similarities with the variation, and it isn't clear to me why you always take b from a, in the part of $\binom{a}{r + b}$, no matter what you will take at least b or more items from a, then the remaining d + b - (r + b) = d - r items are taken from c. For me this doesn't count the cases where all the b+d items are taken from c for example. While $\binom{a + c}{b + d}$ count every form of taking b+d items from a+c including ways of not taking any ítem form a.

What have you tried so far?  Take a look at my edit to see a very basic version of mathjax.

@abiessu For now I tried to do it similar to the Vandermonde's original formula, but it doesn't work. I don't see the part of always counting the forms of taking at least b elements form a equal at counting the ways of taking b+d items from a+c, I mean in this last you count the cases where you don't tale elements from a per example, but in the LFH you always takes at least b from a, so you never count the cases where you don't take elements from a.

I don't think the first identity is correct. For example, let $a=b$. Then $r=0$ is the only possible value, so the left-hand side is $\binom{a}{b}\binom{c}{d}=\binom{c}{d}$, but the right-hand side is $\binom{a+c}{b+d}=\binom{a+c}{a+d}$. In fact, it is already false for $a=b=c=1$, $d=0$, as it claims $1=2$.
